# Time series with additional information

Tags: time-series, pandas, boosting

Given a time series with job-submission counts, how can I predict which certain features about the jobs?

[image]

I need to predict how many jobs and which jobs arrived in some system. Using `pandas.groupby`, I've sliced the data into 15 minutes intervals.

I can predict how many jobs arrived but also need to predict which type of job will arrive and some other features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the displayed time series shows number of jobs submitted per 15 minute interval.

#### Categorical features

Divide the time series per category. If the jobs can be divided into `type1`, `type2`, `type3` then make a time series for each type and predict each series individually. So `type1`-time series has number of `type1`-jobs per 15 minute interval.

#### Continuous features

For continues features *e.g time-to-do-job* you can divide the jobs into categories of `time00`,`time10`, `time20`, `time30` for jobs that take 0-9 minutes, 10-19 minutes, 20-29 minutes etc respectively. As before generate a time-series per division.

Depending on how much data you have and how it is distributed you can make more groups or space them differently.

Comment: thanks it's seems like good option